# Paragaraph not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On my [website](http://photography.soton.ac.uk), the titles above the thumbnails do not show in any version of IE. 
As usual everything works fine in every other modern browser.

the html for a thumbnail is

```
    <div id="s1" class="stumb">
    <p><a href="emily_cotton.html">Emily Cotton</a></p>
    <a href="emily_cotton.html"><img alt="Emily Cotton" src="img/thumbs/ect.jpg"></a>
    </div>
```

the css is

```
p
{
    margin:-20px 0px 0px 0px;
    font: 11px OpenSansRegular, Arial ;
    background: rgb(235,235,235);
    text-align: left;
    padding:0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
```

and

```
.stumb

{
    margin:-20px 0px 0px 0px;
    font: 11px OpenSansRegular, Arial ;
    background: rgb(235,235,235);
    text-align: left;
    padding:0px 2px 0px 2px;
}
```

I tried alternative css, removing the negative margins but this did not work. Besides IE should be able to deal with these negative values anyway. I'm at a point where i am going mad with all the alternative versions floating around, all of them still not showing in IE. My conclusion is that the solution must be so simple that i am blind too it.

Comment: Does your version of IE support font faces? (OpenSansRegular)

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle duplicating the issue?

Comment: It supports font face, the paragraph at the bottom of the page does show and so does the title. They all use FontFace

Comment: Is it possible it's being hidden by the negative margin?

Comment: Have you tried removing the position:absolute from the boxes? You could probably substitute it with float:left if that's the issue.

Comment: I redid the design without negative margins, still had the issue. Will setup a JSfiddle for this

Comment: flipping hell, it looks like it is the negative margins. There must have been some error trying the first time around. Not the same nice design, guess it will be an extra sheet of CSS targetting IE...AGAIN

Comment: FYI if you want to see the difference http://jsfiddle.net/tx6fk/ would be nice to have the whitespace between paragraph and thumbnail as the other browsers...